# AWS GLUE job failure working with partitioned Parquet files in nested s3 folders

Tags: directory, schema, parquet, aws-glue

I get the following error when running a GLUE job over partitioned parquet files 
Unable to infer a schema for Parquet. It must be specified manually

I have set up my crawler and successfully obtained the schema for my parquet files. I can view the data in Athena. I have created the schema manually on my target Redshift.

I can load the files via GLUE into Redshift if all my data is in one folder only.
 BUT when I point at a folder  that has nested folders, e.g. folder X - has 04  and 05  - the GLUE job fails with the message
Unable to infer a schema for Parquet. It must be specified manually

Which is strange as it works if I put all these files into the same folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution here - this works for me 
[Firehose JSON -> S3 Parquet -> ETL Spark, error: Unable to infer schema for Parquet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51050175/firehose-json-s3-parquet-etl-spark-error-unable-to-infer-schema-for-parq/54241085#54241085)

It is the scala version of the ETL glue job

Answer (score 0):

If you point direct at partition folder then partition folder will no longer be column in table schema. It is better to use predicate pushdown - https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/work-with-partitioned-data-in-aws-glue/
while pointing at top folder.

Comment: Hi Sandeep, I tried using the Predicate Pushdown but it only seems to exclude partitions and I want to include all partitions. Can you give any more details of how to achieve what I am after, please? I have a way using scala, but as I am writing most of my scripts in Python i would love to get this working with python.

Comment: then don't use pushdown predicate. But keep location at top folder.
I thought you wanted data for 04 and 05 only. If not, just remove pushdown predicate part and it will return data for all partitions

Comment: that's the problem it doesn't return the data for all partitions, that's why I put up the question to find out if I need to do some extra tweaking. Thanks anyway